# Why does this javascript code to increase font size work in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

I am using this javascript code to increase the font size of the text in a span so that it fills its parent div.

```
    function maximise_font(the_span, the_div, the_fontsize) {
        var fontSize = the_fontsize;                    
        var ourText = the_span;
        var maxHeight = the_div.height();
        var maxWidth = the_div.width();
        var textHeight;
        var textWidth;
        do {
            ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
            textHeight = ourText.height();
            textWidth = ourText.width();
            fontSize = fontSize - 1;
        } while (textHeight > maxHeight || textWidth > maxWidth && fontSize > 3);   
    }
```

It works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome. In Chrome, the inner loop is run the same amount of times as it is in Firefox, but the font size doesn't change at all. Why is that?

Comment: afaik, some browsers do not apply any css styles until the current loop has finished... so in each loop 'font-size' is applied but not rendered so textHeight and width will be the same for each loop until the loop has exited...

Comment: It's not clear what values you're passing to this function.  This would help understand the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming ourText is a jQuery object, it looks like this line is your problem:

```
ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
```

You need to specify a unit type:

```
ourText.css('font-size', fontSize + "px");
```

I'm guessing firefox is just making some assumptions for you.

Answer (score 0):

can you show how your html looks like? I test it here and it works fine for both firefox and chrome.